# List of existing records in custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, controller-extension

I am trying to list the existing records for the current user in my VF Page:

here is the start of my page with the controller and extension defined:

```
<apex:page id="ChangeRequestList" StandardController="Request_for_System_Change__c" extensions="RequestForSystemChangeControllerList"
           standardStylesheets="false" 
            showHeader="false"  > 

<head>
<title>Requests</title>
</head>
```

here is the code for the did that will hold the list:

```
<div class="blueBorder WidthAuto" id="ListRecs">
    <apex:pageblock >
        <br/>
        <apex:commandButton value="List Records" action="{!fetchRecords}" rerender="pbTable"/>
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!listRecords}" var="a" id="pbTable" rendered="{!showRecords}">
            <!-- Name, Owner.Name, Status__c, recordTypeId-->
            <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Owner.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Status__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.recordTypeId}"/>
        </apex:pageblocktable>
    </apex:pageblock>
```

here is my controller:

```
public with sharing class RequestForSystemChangeControllerList {

    private Request_for_System_Change__c objRequest_for_System_Change;
    public List<Request_for_System_Change__c> listRecords {get;set;}

    public RequestForSystemChangeControllerList(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) { 
        //objRequest_for_System_Change = (Request_for_System_Change__c)stdCtrl.getRecords();
        showRecords =false;

        //Request_for_System_Change__c[] allRequests =
            //[select name from Request_for_System_Change__c    where ownerid=:userInfo.getUserID()];
    }

    public Boolean showRecords{get;set;}    

    //In constructor

    public void fetchRecords(){     

        listRecords = [Select Name, Owner.Name, Status__c, recordTypeId from Request_for_System_Change__c 
                      where ownerid=:userInfo.getUserID()];
        system.debug('records returned' + listRecords.size());
        // you need to place a limit of 1000 as VF supports max of 1000 recors to be displayed
        showRecords = true;
    }
}
```

when `Preview` the vf page, I see the `div` with the command button **List Records**.

I click the button, and in the Developer Console logs I can see that 3 records have been returned but the table is not being displayed:

```
14:59:09:188 USER_DEBUG [23]|DEBUG|records returned3
```

so what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your table inside `apex:outputpanel` and rerender `apex:outputpanel`

This will solve your problem

```
<apex:outputpanel id="pbTable">
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!listRecords}" var="a"  rendered="{!showRecords}">
            <!-- Name, Owner.Name, Status__c, recordTypeId-->
            <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Owner.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Status__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.recordTypeId}"/>
        </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Also check `showRecords` true or not